# Is it possible to have a dynamic product title on the product page?

Tags: php

i am using the colour swatch exstension on magento, and i have a set of configurable products (all of them longsleeve hoodys) i have 10 configurable products, each one a different colour of said hoodys; in each hoody product page, they display all available colours.

E.G Red hoody shows all colours available, like black green yellow ect... 
The black hoody does the same.

Except, if i am in the black hoody product, and select 'red' as a colour, it works as the image changes and the colour is selected.

But the title stays the same, and this may become a problem for the people that pick/pack the order, as on their picking sheet it will say "Black Hoody Top (Red, Small)" and the packer / picking may get confused and send the wrong order, so i was wondering is there a way to have the title dynamic to the colour swatch option? Or if there is a way to just have all colour swatch attributes as links to the corresponding product page?

So if i was on black hoody, and selected the colour red, it will load up the red hoody?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in simple answer yes

Comment: are you switching the color with javascript or does the page refreshes?

Comment: I am using an extension, that using js